# WFS propertyname can not filter nillable="false" field

Tags: geoserver, wfs, propertyname

GeoServer WFS GetFeature propertyname does not work for `nillable="false"`  field, nillable="false"  field always returns.

Comment: Please add DescribeFeatureType of your feature type. And please use plain text, not a screen capture image.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do, can you please expand your question with the query you are trying to make

Comment: i hope only return name field, but it return all nuillable=false field;

Comment: can i set not return nuillable=false field default

Answer (score 2):

The server seems to work as supposed. Excerpt from the WFS standard:

> **Propertyname**: A list of non-mandatory properties to include in the response.

The mandatory properties are always included in the response. If the property is not nillable then it is mandatory.